# Retrieve the collection of unionOf and intersectionOf for each OWL

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I'm trying to extract `intersectionOf` and `unionOf` in an OWL file, where `interesctionOf` and `unionOf` consist of collection of classes, `someValuesFrom` or/and `onProperty`. I have created a SPARQL query which extracts the "collection" for the `intersectionOf`, but the problem is that some of the retrieved data are not related to the class.

For example, I have class called `man`. This class has an equivalent class which is `intersectionOf` of three classes, namely, `adult`,`person`, and `male` .My SPARQL query returns some incorrect result: it returns that the classes `adult`, `person`, and `male` are equivalent to class `man` (i.e., this part is correct), but they are also equivalent classes to all other classes in my OWL file such as `haulage_worker`, which is incorrect. Here is my SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX abc: <http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#>
PREFIX ghi: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX mno: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX list: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/list#>

SELECT  Distinct ?class ?equivalentClass  
WHERE{ ?class a owl:Class .
FILTER( STRSTARTS(STR(?class),"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#") || STRSTARTS(STR(?class),"http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#") 

)

     ?x a owl:Class ; owl:intersectionOf ?list .
     ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?equivalentClass .


   } GROUP BY ?class ?equivalentClass ORDER BY ?no
```

and this is my OWL file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:ns0="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#"
  xml:base="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#haulage_worker">
    <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
   ></rdfs:comment>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty      rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#works_for"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
              <owl:Restriction>
               <owl:onProperty>
                <owl:ObjectProperty    rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#part_of"/>
               </owl:onProperty>
               <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class   rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#haulage_company"/>
               </owl:someValuesFrom>
              </owl:Restriction>
              <owl:Class   rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#haulage_company"/>
            </owl:unionOf>
          </owl:Class>
         </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
     </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >haulage worker</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#man">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#adult"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#person"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#male"/>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This is the output which I got (they are not correct output):

```
-----------------------------------------
    | class               | equivalentClass |
    =========================================
    | abc:adult           | abc:adult       |
    | abc:adult           | abc:male        |
    | abc:adult           | abc:person      |
    | abc:haulage_company | abc:adult       |
    | abc:haulage_company | abc:male        |
    | abc:haulage_company | abc:person      |
    | abc:haulage_worker  | abc:adult       |
    | abc:haulage_worker  | abc:male        |
    | abc:haulage_worker  | abc:person      |
    | abc:male            | abc:adult       |
    | abc:male            | abc:male        |
    | abc:male            | abc:person      |
    | abc:man             | abc:adult       |
    | abc:man             | abc:male        |
    | abc:man             | abc:person      |
    | abc:person          | abc:adult       |
    | abc:person          | abc:male        |
    | abc:person          | abc:person      |
    | owl:Thing           | abc:adult       |
    | owl:Thing           | abc:male        |
    | owl:Thing           | abc:person      |
    -----------------------------------------
```

The expected output would be like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
    | class               | equivalentClass |
    =========================================
    | abc:adult           | abc:adult       |
    | abc:adult           | abc:male        |
    | abc:adult           | abc:person      |
    | abc:haulage_company |                 |
    | abc:haulage_company |                 |
    | abc:haulage_company |                 |
    | abc:haulage_worker  |                 |
    | abc:haulage_worker  |                 |
    | abc:haulage_worker  |                 |
    | abc:male            | abc:adult       |
    | abc:male            | abc:male        |
    | abc:male            | abc:person      |
    | abc:man             | abc:adult       |
    | abc:man             | abc:male        |
    | abc:man             | abc:person      |
    | abc:person          | abc:adult       |
    | abc:person          | abc:male        |
    | abc:person          | abc:person      |
    | owl:Thing           |                 |
    | owl:Thing           |                 |
    | owl:Thing           |                 |
    -----------------------------------------
```

What should I change in my SPARQL query in order to make my output like the previous table?

Comment: This really should have been posted as an updated version of your older question, [How to extract onProperty, someValuesFrom, intersectionOf for each class in OWL file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19403359/1281433), but this really is a very nice improvement.  Thank you for taking the time to clean this up.  (I'm voting to close the older question as a duplicate of this one, though, since we don't need both of them around.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning up your query a bit, we have:

```
prefix abc: <http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#>
prefix ghi: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix mno: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix list: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/list#>

select distinct ?class ?equivalentClass where {
  ?class a owl:Class .
  filter( strstarts(str(?class),str(owl:)) ||     # since "owl:" is an IRI, you can 
          strstarts(str(?class),str(abc:))    )   # use str(owl:) and str(:abc)

  ?x a owl:Class ; 
     owl:intersectionOf ?list .
     ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?equivalentClass .
}
group by ?class ?equivalentClass
order by ?class                                   # ?class, not ?no
```

Your problem lies in that you're selecting `?class`, which can be every `owl:Class` in the ontology (as long as it starts with an appropriate prefix), and then selecting `?equivalentClass` from the list of intersection classes of `?x`, and `?x` has no connection whatsoever to `?class.  (You were also sorting by`?no`, but I think you meant to sort by`?class`.)

Figuring out the *right* query to write will be easier if we take a look at the data in a more human readable format, e.g., Turtle.  In Turtle, the `man` class is:

```
ns0:man  a                   owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a                   owl:Class ;
                               owl:intersectionOf  ( ns0:adult ns0:person ns0:male )
                             ] .
```

You're looking for things which are `owl:Class`es, are related by `owl:equivalentClass` to something else that's an `owl:Class`, and which has a list value for `owl:intersectionOf`.  This isn't too hard in SPARQL, and the query actually has the same kind of structure as this Turtle text:

```
prefix abc: <http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#>
prefix ghi: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix mno: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix list: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/list#>

select distinct ?class ?otherClass where {
  ?class a owl:Class ;
         owl:equivalentClass [ a owl:Class ;
                               owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?otherClass ] ] .
  filter( strstarts(str(?class),str(owl:)) ||
          strstarts(str(?class),str(abc:))    )
}
group by ?class ?otherClass
order by ?class
```

I changed the variable name from `equivalentClass` to `otherClass`, because `adult`, `male`, and `person` aren't *equivalent* to `man`.  Their intersection is.  Using Jena's command line `sparql` tool, you'll get results like this:

```
$ sparql --data data.rdf --query query.rq
------------------------
| class   | otherClass |
========================
| abc:man | abc:adult  |
| abc:man | abc:male   |
| abc:man | abc:person |
------------------------
```

This query only retrieves classes that are equivalent to some intersection.  Your expected results showed all the classes whose IRIs started with `abc:` or `owl:`, which means that the extra structure is actually optional, so we adjust the query accordingly by wrapping the optional parts in `optional { … }`, and we get the kind of results we're looking for:

```
prefix abc: <http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/people#>
prefix ghi: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix mno: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix list: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/list#>

select distinct ?class ?otherClass where {
  ?class a owl:Class .
  optional { 
    ?class owl:equivalentClass [ a owl:Class ;
                                 owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?otherClass ] ] .
  }
  filter( strstarts(str(?class),str(owl:)) ||
          strstarts(str(?class),str(abc:))    )
}
group by ?class ?otherClass
order by ?class
```

```
$ sparql --data data.rdf --query query.rq
------------------------------------
| class               | otherClass |
====================================
| abc:adult           |            |
| abc:haulage_company |            |
| abc:haulage_worker  |            |
| abc:male            |            |
| abc:man             | abc:adult  |
| abc:man             | abc:male   |
| abc:man             | abc:person |
| abc:person          |            |
| owl:Thing           |            |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dear Joshua Taylor, It works fine now :) many thanks for your helps I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AbdullahAlmuhaimeed I'm glad to hear that it helped!  On Stack Overflow, when an answer works for you, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) to let others know that it solved your problem, and to reduce the number of questions without accepted answers.  It also gives you and the answer-er a bit of reputation.

Comment: Deat Joshua Taylor, I'm sorry I'm quite new in Stack Overfollow website, I did not know that I should accept the answer when it works with me I thought only reply in comment enough, sorry :)

Comment: @AbdullahAlmuhaimeed There's nothing to be sorry about! Everybody is new for a while, after all!  I'm glad that this was able to help you.  Happy SPARQL'ing!

Comment: Many thanks for your kindness Joshua Taylor :) . And now I'm working on extracting the unionOf section and I'm try to follow your advices, it does not work yet, but I'm keep trying and I hope it works with me :)

Comment: Dear @Joshua Taylor I have new update in my previous question where I have posted my new question under the previous one. Because as I told you yesterday I tried to extract the unionOf and onProperty in the first class of my file, but unfortunately, it does not return any result. If you have any idea can you please help me with it. I'm really sorry to disturb you with me , but I spent too much time trying to identify the problem in my SPARQL query , but I couldn't. Many thanks for your helps :)

Comment: @AbdullahAlmuhaimeed You've already accepted an answer to this question, but by changing the question, you've made the accepted answer incorrect, as it doesn't address what's _now_ being asked.  I'm going to rollback the edit;  please ask your new question as a separate question (and then I, and others, will be happy to take a look).

Comment: Dear Joshua Taylor, I'm sorry for this mistake and sorry to disturb you with me :), I have posted a new quetion with title :" Extracting Class content such as (onProperty, somevalueFrom , unioinOf (which contain a collection) and equivalentClass)" . If you have any idea please help me with it . Many thanks in advance :)